# How to read values of a key from a json file in a helm template

Tags: go, kubernetes, github-actions, kubernetes-helm

I am creating a github actions step

```
.
.
.
steps:
  name: export-secrets
  run: |
    echo '${{ toJSON(secrets) }}' >> gh-secrets.json
.
.
.
```

suppose the gh-secrets.json file is as below:

```
# gh-secrets.json
{"A": "a1", "B": "b1", "C": "c1"}
```

Then I am going to pull the helm charts and untar them and then move `gh-secrets.json` into the untar directory. The reason I am doing this is according to [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/), "Files outside of a helm application subchart, including those of the parent, cannot be accessed"

suppose I have these files in the untar directory

```
# values.yaml
secrets:
  - A
  - B
```

and I have `templates/secrets.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-secret
data:
    {{- range .Values.secrtes }}
      {{ . }}: {{ $.Files.Get "gh-secrets.json" | toJson }}
    {{- end }}
```

this is the result:

```
# Source: mktplc-catalog/templates/secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: release-name-secret
data:
      A: "'{\"A\": \"a1\", \"B\": \"b1\", \"C\": \"c1\"}'"
      B: "'{\"A\": \"a1\", \"B\": \"b1\", \"C\": \"c1\"}'"
```

but I want it to be

```
# Source: mktplc-catalog/templates/secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: release-name-secret
data:
      A: "a1"
      B: "b1"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253290/discussion-on-question-by-amin-ba-how-to-read-values-of-a-key-from-a-json-file-i); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Helm includes a [`fromJson`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#fromjson) function; in fact, its documentation fairly closely matches your updated setup.  So you can use this to read in the file, parse it, and then select the specific key out of it.

```yaml
data:
{{- $secrets := .Files.Get "gh-secrets.json" | fromJson -}}
{{- range .Values.secrets }}
  {{ . }}: {{ index $secrets . }}
{{- end }}
```

You appear to have some control over the input structure here.  If you can wrap the secret values in some top-level key

```bash
echo '{"secretValues": ${{ toJSON(secrets) }}}' > gh-secrets.json
```

then you can provide this as an extra values file to Helm (valid JSON files are also valid YAML)

```bash
helm install -f gh-secrets.json ...
```

This file doesn't need to be in the chart directory.  Now Helm will parse it for you, and it will be available as `.Values.secretValues` matching the injected key.  (Remember that the `range` loop resets the value of `.`, so you will need to save its value outside the loop.)

If this technique works for you, it might be possible to use it to directly inject the secret values without the layer of indirection; use something like

```yaml
data:
{{ .Values.secretValues | toYaml | indent 2 }}
```

Comment: your second solution is a very interesting one because it opens the door to other possibilities; for example, suppose I pull secrets from hashicorp vault and it has sub-paths. by the way, you are missing something in the second solution. Here for example `{{ .Values.secretValues | toYaml | indent 2 }}`, you are missing that I don't want all secrets to go to my k8s secret. you should have noticed that my gh-secrets.json has three k, v pairs but I only need A and B.

Comment: I should test but I think the command should be `helm install .... --values gh-secrets.json ...`

Comment: I dont understand this part: `Remember that the range loop resets the value of ., so you will need to save its value outside the loop`

Comment: [awesome](https://helm-playground.com/#t=LQhQBMEMBdILlAAkQbxcRASAVgZwPYB2icAvIgHQBqkANgK4CmuFujAxgE6PQ0POIAvoKSp0iTpEIBzRpT5MWbLj1xCRyNJXVwxiWdCx4i24aLQZGhcOtBA&v=LQhQGcFMGMCdIC4DUCGAbArpcAuABKHngIL4BEKAjGYXgELkBG1tAwudC1HIrgUcBK1BdIA)

Comment: with your second solution I get `error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}`